# sfdx CLI connect to org behind VPN

Tags: salesforcedx

when I am in my company's VPN, my connection to orgs through CLI is failed; but if I am off VPN, those connections are fine. I don't know how to set up to allow that. and I need to be in VPN in order to get through company firewall. below is the org connection status. If I off VPN, they will all show as connected instead of ECONNREFUSED

```
     ALIAS         USERNAME              ORG ID              CONNECTED STATUS
───  ────────────  ────────────────────  ──────────────────  ────────────────
(D)  DevHub        yi.tan@developer.com  00D1U000000Dm6tUAC  ECONNREFUSED
     YiTanSandbox  yi.tan@igt.com.yitan  00D1F000000DWNQUA4  ECONNREFUSED
```

Comment: You will likely need to work with your corporate IT department to grant you access to Salesforce when the VPN is active. This isn't something the community here is going to be of much help with.

Comment: @MarkPond thank you very much for answering my question. I can access all salesforce orgs just fine through browser and third party application when VPN is on. It seems like only CLI is not working with VPN. Is there any specific configuration I need to setup with CLI?

Comment: There is no specific configuration with the CLI. Your IT department should be able to look at the logs of the VPN app and see why the connection is being refused and adjust as necessary.